# How do I sort two arrays the same way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two arrays:

```
a = [6, 4, 3]
b = [1, 3, 4]
```

I call `a.sort`:

```
a.sort = [3, 4, 6]
```

How do I sort array `b` so the values have the same position to values in array `a` before the sort?

It would be now:

```
b = [4, 3, 1]
```

So that values in `b` have the same position to values in array `a`.

Comment: what is your sorting method? something you wrote, or a library you're using?

Comment: I just call .sort in my rails console think it uses Comparable

Comment: You want `b` to have the same sorting logic as `a` before sorting?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could combine both the arrays into one using the [`zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-zip) method. Once you combine a and b, you would get,

```
[[6, 1], [4, 3], [3, 4]]
```

Now sort the arrays, which would sort them based on the first element of each sub-array resulting in,

```
[[3, 4], [4, 3], [6, 1]]
```

Now we want to do the reverse of zip to get the first and second elements of each sub-array into a new array. Using [`transpose`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-transpose), we can get it back in the original form as,

```
[[3, 4, 6], [4, 3, 1]]
```

Thankfully using parallel assignment all of this is possible in one line. Here's the full code,

```
x, y = a.zip(b).sort.transpose
```

Now `x` should contain `[3, 4, 6]`, and `y` should contain `[4, 3, 1]`.

Comment: Just used a, b instead of x, y

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [6, 4, 3]
b = [1, 3, 4]

ra, rb = a.zip(b).sort_by(&:first).transpose
# ra => [3, 4, 6]
# rb => [4, 3, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're trying to achieve, and I'm sure others could come up with a more elegant solution, but I would use a Hash instead. Assign the values of a `a` as the key, and the values of `b` as the values. You could iterate over a to accomplish this, or just in advance when you're creating this data. The result should be:

```
$ hash
=> {6 => 1, 4 => 3, 3 => 4}
    a0   b0 a1   b1 a2   b2
$ hash.sort
=> [[3, 4], [4, 3], [6, 1]]
```

Like I said, not super smooth, but I've got turkey hangover...

Answer (score 0):

```
[a, b].transpose.sort { |x, y| x[0] <=> y[0] }.transpose[1]
=> [4, 3, 1]
```

or

```
a, b = [a, b].transpose.sort { |x, y| x[0] <=> y[0] }.transpose
```

Comment: You should always use `sort_by` for a keyed sort. Not only is it more readable, it's also more efficient.